# GNSS algorithms in Android and IOS

Tags: gps, android

I am trying to determine what algorithms are used to determine location and speed in late-model Android and IOS smartphones.  I am looking into merging the location data with higher frequency IMU data to determine if dead reckoning is feasible.  I am looking at a very specific application where prior opinion determined that gyroscope errors will prevent dead reckoning to be reliable.

I would be helpful to see what the Android and IOS algorithm process for I don't want to apply the same IMU data the same way.

Comment: What part of Android are you looking at?  My work with u-Blox GNSS and Sierra Wireless GNSS on Android indicates that Android feeds locations from GNSS Receiver more-or-less directly to Location Services, with WiFi and Cellular network positioning thrown in every now and then.  Google ARCore is different in that it combines whatever is available, I have no idea of the algorithm thus this is a comment not and answer!

Comment: I have an application where the platform is stable.  Thus, it might be possible to add dead reckoning in between GNSS fixes.  I understand that Android provides a "fused" location service where WiFi ranging-based data may be included or substituted if GNSS is not available as in indoor locations.  Although the Broadcom chip is capable of up to 15 samples per second, Android reports GNSS updates at somewhat arbitrary times (~ 1 per sec depending on processing).  That's why I am wondering what's going on in between reports.  For stable enough for dead reckoning, am I "reusing" data?